# MVC 5 How to bind linq result(Number) to array[i]?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

Let's say i have a inventory slot range from 1 to 100 how to find the first empty slot from the range?

First, i'm thinking of using Array.FindIndex but i'm stuck at here.

```
var InventorySlot = (from i in db.InventoryModel where i.userId == 1 select i.slot).ToArray();

int index = Array.FindIndex(InventorySlot, item => item == null );
```

But this will create

- InventorySlot[0] = 1
- InventorySlot[1] = 3
- InventorySlot[2] = 4

So how to create like this?

- InventorySlot[1] = x
- InventorySlot[3] = x
- InventorySlot[4] = x

Perhaps i can use Array.FindIndex to locate the empty array? The index variable i need is 2(First empty number in the array)

Comment: A linq query with `where i.SlotId == 1` will never return rows where `i` is null. Why do you think `InventorySlot[2]` is or should be `null`?

Comment: @GSerg, this depends on what is being selected in the linq query. The above code has no select.

Comment: Sorry guys the linq is mix korea word so you all might not able to understand easily so i simply change it more understandable. now just assume the linq will work.

Comment: You probably want a *Dictionary* and not an array.

Comment: I think you need to add some types - what is the type of `index` or `i.slot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is compare the result from the database with the range without exceptions:

```
var firstEmptySlot = Enumerable.Range(1, InventorySlot.Max()).Except(InventorySlot).First();
```

If you want to get the largest slot plus one if no slot is empty, you can do:

```
var firstEmptySlot = Enumerable.Range(1, InventorySlot.Max()+1).Except(InventorySlot).First();
```

You would need to test `firstEmptySlot` in this case to make sure it is <= 100.

You could combine testing and the query by limiting the range to 1 - 100:

```
var firstEmptySlot = Enumerable.Range(1, Math.Min(InventorySlot.Max()+1, 100)).Except(InventorySlot).FirstOrDefault();
```

You will get a `0` back if no empty slots from 1 - 100 are available.

Comment: Thanks. somehow It works like a charms. Although i don't understand the `var firstEmptySlot = Enumerable.Range(1, InventorySlot.Max()+1).Except(InventorySlot).First();` but both return same value.

Comment: The second expression is for when no slot is skipped. Let's say you have slots 1 - 10 already used. The first expression will give an error, the second expression will return 11. I added another query that combines testing 1 - 100 with finding the first empty slot.